# How do I open a link directly onto a web browser

Tags: java, url

I'm experimenting with opening a link directly on to a web browser. This snippet of code has no errors. However, when run, the website does not pop up in the web browser. How do I fix this?

```
    if (str1.toLowerCase().contains("will pigs fly"))
        pigs();


    public static void pigs(){
        try{

            String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQo0TfuueaY";
            String cmd = "cmd.exe /c start " + url;
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        }catch(Exception ex){}

    }
```

Comment: Did you try running the command outside of Java to check if it works in the first place?

Comment: You are ignoring any exceptions that might have happened here. Add a print statement to see if any were thrown.

Comment: Congratz for the youtube click(s)! This code works fine! ;)